# Getting error while trying to install MQTT Connector (Source and Sink)

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, confluent-platform

I'm trying to connect the MQTT broker with Kafka. I want to install a connector. So I copied this command: `confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-mqtt:1.4.0` from confluent's official website. But I'm getting these errors:

```
confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-mqtt:1.4.0
Do you want to install this into /usr/share/confluent-hub-components? (yN) y

 
Component's license: 
Confluent Software Evaluation License 
https://www.confluent.io/software-evaluation-license 
I agree to the software license agreement (yN) y

Downloading component Kafka Connect MQTT 1.4.0, provided by Confluent, Inc. from Confluent Hub and installing into /usr/share/confluent-hub-components 
Do you want to uninstall existing version 1.4.0? (yN) y

Detected Worker's configs: 
  1. Standard: /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties 
  2. Standard: /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties 
  3. Standard: /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties 
  4. Standard: /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties 
  5. Used by Connect process with PID : /tmp/confluent.B3k50ol5/connect/connect.properties 
Do you want to update all detected configs? (yN) y

Adding installation directory to plugin path in the following files: 
  /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties 
Unable to update Worker's configuration file /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties 
Unable to save to file /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties 
 
Error: Unknown error
```

I already tried with ubuntu 18.04 lts and ubuntu 20.04 lts but still getting the same errors. Please tell me what is wrong here and how could I install this connector?

Comment: Did you try picking a single file instead of all properties? What file permissions are set on the properties? Did you try using sudo?

Comment: sudo is not supported here, so I update the permission using "sudo chmod 777 <folder location>". But here I'm facing another problem. The new files and folders were creating without write permission. it was not possible for me to update the permission for all the files and folders of that plugin. finally, I used "sudo chmod -R 777 <folder location>" and it solved the problem.

Comment: You said sudo is not supported, but were able to use chmod with it?? You don't need write or execute permissions for JAR files, anyway, so 644 would be better

Comment: I can not install with sudo but I can update permission with sudo. so I did